# How can I use a defined string constant in DataTable.Select() method?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the `Select` command to select particular data rows from a DataTable:

```
DataRow[] dr;
dr = dataTable.Select("Roll_No = '"+rNo+"'");
```

I am getting the correct answer, but what if I want to use a constant defined for Roll_No?

I have defined constants:

```
public const string ROLL_NUMBER = "Roll_No";
```

So what will be the code for `DataTable.Select()`?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your correctly, just substitute the variable for the hard-coded value.

```
var rows = dataTable.Select(string.Format("{0} = '{1}'", ROLL_NUMBER, rNo));
```

Assuming `Roll_No` is a numeric field, those single parentheses in the `Select` statement might mess up your query... if you don't get the expected results, try removing them.

Alternatively, you've also got the option of using a LINQ statement:

```
var rows = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(x => x.Field<int>(ROLL_NUMBER) == rNo);
```

***Update** (from follow-up comment):*

> can I use like follows? var dr = datTable.Select("Constants.ROLL_NUMBER = '"+rNo+"'"); here , Constants.ROLL_NUMBER is constant defined for roll number.

No, because your variable name is inside of a quote and so you'll end up filtering on the string literal "ROLL_NUMBER", not the underlying column name stored in ROLL_NUMBER.

To use your code, you'd do it like this:

```
var dr = dataTable.Select(Constants.ROLL_NUMBER = "'" + rNo + "'");
```

Comment: can I use like follows?

var dr = datTable.Select("Constants.ROLL_NUMBER = '"+rNo+"'");
here , Constants.ROLL_NUMBER is constant defined for roll number.

Answer (score 0):

A string is a string.  You already know how to concatenate strings because you're already doing it.  `ROLL_NUMBER` would just be another string, just like `rNo` in your current code.

That said, I would tend to use `String.Format` for that sort of expression.

Answer (score 0):

dataTable.Select() Method can only pass strings. Just Like it

public DataRow[] Select(string filterExpression,string sort)

If You want to pass a constant than you have to convert it into string.